# How to achieve transactional behaviour in nested non-transactional calls?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, rollback

I am new to spring-boot JPA and am trying to apply transactional behaviour in nested calls.

I have a service which is having `@Transactional` method (`Public`). This method invokes many other service methods which are non-transactional and these methods perform save/update (Also there is possibility of nested calls going more than 2-3 levels).

In case of runtime exception in top level method (which is Transactional) I want to roll back all DB writes which has been done by nested call. Following is an example for better understanding.

```
@Service
public class ServiceA{

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB bService;

  @Transactional
  public void process(){
    bService.process();

    //Here is Some code that might throw RuntimeException
    // Requirement is whatever above one or many nested calls modified DB must perform rollback. 

  }

}

@Service 
public class ServiceB{
  @Autowired
  private ServiceC cService;
  public void process(){
    cService.process();
  }  
}
@Service 
public class ServiceC{
  @Autowired
  private SomeJpaRepo repository;
  public void process(){
    // repository doing some DB CRUD our. 
  }  
}
```

Above is simple reproduction of my use case but it is having tens of nested calls upto many nested levels, `Transaction` is not rolling back in case of exception in `ServiceA.process()` (`ServiceA.process()` is invoked by a Rest Controller). I can see logs  `Completing transaction for bla bla` but I can see no rollback in DB.
I am wondering whether it is actually possible? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: This should actually work… are you importing `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` or `javax.transaction.Transactional`?

Comment: I am using `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: And from where are you calling the annotated method?

Comment: From rest controller

Comment: Are you sure, that you have  `@Transactional` only on the top level? Maybe somewhere inside you have  `@Transactional(TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`? Also how do you check that a tranaction is no rolled back?